# Energy loss in transformer

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, dissipation

There is energy loss in transformer due to Eddy current,leakage of flux and resistance of coils . But we assume in calculation a ideal condition. So if there is pure inductor then how could power dissipate Because energy given to inductor in 1/2 cycle= energy given by inductor in second 1/2 cycle .

Comment: People who are calculating real transformers aren't making the assumption that the inductors are ideal. They are modelling all of the above plus the hysteresis of the core materials. At most you can ask how that is done.

Comment: You might be interested in this article, [Power transformers](http://www.egr.unlv.edu/~eebag/TRANSFORMERS.pdf), in which first an ideal transformer is described and then the equivalent circuit for a lossy transformer is discussed.

Comment: The most important part of your question is th "if" in " if there is pure inductor", in reality without superconducting coils there are NO pure inductors so it is introduced just to see the principle of transformers , not to model reality.